# How to make flask response in one tcp packet?

Tags: python, flask

I am using flask for a very simple app. The response is right but split into multiple tcp packets. It seems that flask put every http header in a tcp packet.

Why flask response is split into multiple tcp packets? How do I disable this feature?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? TCP is another level of network abstraction, you should not interfere with it.

Answer (score 1):

Flask is microframework, it is used for developing webapp or related stuff,

Flask has its own response building way, you can not control response packets from flask.

What you are talking is of different layer, it comes about networking layer.